# Dropdown pagination in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

Is it possible to have a dropdown pagination like the image below with jquery datatables?
[image]

Comment: Can you share how you achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - with a plug-in such as this: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination#listbox

Answer (score 0):

With Select pagination plugin list you can achieve this.

Import select.js along with your datatable js files.

You can use CDN `//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/pagination/select.js`

Example:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#example').dataTable( {
              "sPaginationType": "listbox"
          } );
      } );
```

Comment: Yes, it answers the OP, but how to have pagingType + listbox together ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a select box pagination with default `DataTables pagination` without using any DataTables pagination plugin, you could use the following source code :

```
var dataTable = $('#customer_data').DataTable({
    processing : true,
    serverSide : true,
    // order : [],
    // dom: 'Bfrtip',
    retrieve: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'fetch.php,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            start: start,
            length: length
        }
    },
    drawCallback: function( settings ) {
      var page_info = dataTable.page.info();
      $('#totalpages').text(page_info.pages);
      var html = '';
      var start = 0;
      var length = page_info.length;
      for(var count = 1; count <= page_info.pages; count++) {         
          var page_number = count - 1;
          html += '<option value="'+page_number+'" data-start="'+start+'" data-length="'+length+'">'+count+'</option>';
          start = start + page_info.length;
      }
      $('#pagelist').html(html);
      $('#pagelist').val(page_info.page);
    }
});
```

I have found [this source code](https://www.webslesson.info/2021/04/how-to-add-custom-select-box-pagination-in-jquery-datatable-with-ajax-php.html).

After adding above code, you will be able to implement dropdown pagination in jQuery DataTables and the output will look like below :

[image: dropdown pagination in jQuery DataTables]

Comment: Yes, but works only in case of classic use. As soon as custom classes are used, this process becomes complicated. On the other hand, it gives you ideas for development.