# Display page numbers in drop down in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatable

I was trying to check whether we can display the page numbers in a drop down instead of displaying 1 2 3 4 etc. Unfortunately I didn't get the right solution

Do I need to add any parameter in the datatables option

```
theDtable = tableobj.DataTable({ 
      "paging": true
} )
```

All other posts were displaying only about page rows or page length

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropdown pagination in jQuery DataTables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137953/dropdown-pagination-in-jquery-datatables)

Comment: @Aminur.. yes it is.