# Multiple pagination options in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm displaying the pagination buttons as 1 2 3 4 etc for navigation. When I use the option

```
 "sPaginationType": "listbox"
```

It displays only in drop down format.

Can I have both options of buttons and drop down pagination option in datatable

Answer (score 0):

I have already give answer of the same question in other, so please check this [Dropdown pagination in jQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137953/dropdown-pagination-in-jquery-datatables/67190389#67190389) this will help you for find solution of your query.

Answer (score -1):

```
'sPaginationType' : 'full_numbers',
'sPaginationType' : 'listbox'
```

use both as shown in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ybbmagqx/91/)

Comment: ... the fiddle doesn't work? only shows the full numbers format