# Two different types of pagination on datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, pagination

How do I add two types of pagination at the same time? I always added one type or another.

What I want to archive:

[image]

Let's use a simple example of multiple paginations, the two types:

```
<table id=test>

<thead>
    <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>a1</td><td>b1</td><td>c1</td><td>d1</td></tr>

    <tr><td>a2</td><td>b2</td><td>c2</td><td>d2</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

```
    $('#test').dataTable(
    {
      "paging": true, 
      "sDom":'ftipp'
    });
```

or

```
$('#test').dataTable(
    {
      "paging": true,
      //"pagingType": "full_numbers",
      "pagingType": "listbox",
      "sDom":'ftipp'
    });
```

using
http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/pagination/select.js

The result is

[image]

or this one:

[image]

And I want to have one normal pagination and one with the select. How can I archive this? It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have already give answer of the same question under this question, so check [Dropdown pagination in jQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137953/dropdown-pagination-in-jquery-datatables/67190389#67190389) this answer for your query, in which how to add two different type of pagination in single DataTable.